# Apache php httpd-xampp.conf alias not working

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-alias

I have httpd-xampp.conf with

```
<IfModule alias_module>
...
    Alias /examples "D:/xampp/htdocs/examples/" 
    <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/examples">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

an in examples folder i have index.html, but when i access `http://localhost:8880/examples`, i have error

```
This page was not found

You are not logged in.

Back Log in Issues
```

Is there any error of my config? other alias : phpmyadmin, security work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change httpd-xampp.conf to

```
<IfModule alias_module>
...
    #!!! Don't know why
    #Alias /examples "D:/xampp/examples/" don't work 

    Alias /my-examples "D:/xampp/examples/" 
    <Directory "D:/xampp/examples">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info|my-examples))">
        Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

and `http://localhost:8880/my-examples` work now